# how to calculate 38 days from next month starting in Python

Tags: python

For example let us consider invoice_date = 09/11/2021

but is payment_period is for 38 days  then it should start from 1/12/2021 to 7/01/2022 (because december month have 31 days) then the due_date will be 7/01/2022

the invoice_date can be any date of the month but payment_period should start form 1st date of next upcoming month and due_date should be 38th date from that

today = datetime.date.today() (#09/10/11)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Django question, but a Python question.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

invoice_date = date(2021, 11, 9)
period_start = (invoice_date.replace(day=1) + timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1)
period_end = period_start + timedelta(days=37)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dt = datetime.date.today()

first_day_of_next_month = (dt.replace(day=1) + datetime.timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1)

payment_due_date = first_day_of_next_month + datetime.timedelta(days=37)
```

Edit: explanation, and correction (37 days should be added instead of 38)

A [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object represents a duration, the difference between two dates or times. The replace instance method returns a date with the same value, except for those parameters given new values by whichever keyword arguments are specified ([on the same page under instance methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta))

So the first_day_of_next_month is calculated by first calling replace on the day of the current date, turning every possible date into the first of the current month. This is the dt.replace(day=1) part of the code. Then a timedelta is added of 32 days, guaranteeing that the date will now be in the following month regardless of how many days the current month has. This is the + datetime.timedelta(days=32) part of the code. But we don't know what day we're at in the next month, because a month can have 28, 29, 30, or 31 days, so another replace is called on the date we've just calculated to set the day at 1. The code is equivalent to:

```
dt = dt.replace(day=1) # turn date into first of current month
dt = dt + datetime.timedelta(days=32) # now we're guaranteed in next month, but unsure which day
first_day_of_next_month = dt.replace(day=1) # now we're on the first of next month
```

And to get the date that falls exactly 38 days after first_day_of_next_month, just add a timedelta of 37 days.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you find the first day of next mounth** :-

And use this

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from calendar import monthrange

days_in_month = lambda dt: monthrange(dt.year, dt.month)[1]
today = date.today()
first_day = today.replace(day=1) + timedelta(days_in_month(today))
print(first_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer using arrow for any date related operations, it's a lot easier to remember as `shift` and `replace` pretty much cover everything.

```
# Convert the date string
>>> a = arrow.get('09/11/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
<Arrow [2021-11-09T00:00:00+00:00]>

# Get the first day of the next month
>>> a = a.shift(months=1).replace(day=1)
<Arrow [2021-12-01T00:00:00+00:00]>

# Move ahead 30 days
>>> a = a.shift(days=38)
<Arrow [2022-01-08T00:00:00+00:00]>

>>> a.format('DD/MM/YYYY')
'08/01/2022'
```